# dotnet run/build - How to specify where the packages are?

Tags: .net, nuget, .net-core

Since I am using CI integration I cannot (and don't want) to put packages to shared user folder. Instead I want them restore inside the actual folder (think node_modules).

So that is simple, I run `dotnet restore --no-cache --packages Packages` and it works fine. Packages are restored and they are in the correct folder.

However when I run `dotnet build -c Release` or `dotnet run -c Release` it cannot find no packages.

> /var/www/website/project.json(15,50): error NU1001: The dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting >= 1.0.0 could not be resolved.

**So how to make sure dotnet knows where to look for packages for this specific project?**

Here is how my folders look like where I execute the commands.

```
bin
bundleconfig.json
NuGet.config
Packages
project.json
Properties
web.config
bower.json
Controllers
obj
Program.cs
project.lock.json
ViewsWeb.xproj
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okey, so for now there is no such option and actually `--packages` seems to be some legacy parameter.

Anyway, in order to make it work we need to set env variable `NUGET_PACKAGES=/var/www/website/Packages`

Of course this sucks in a way that I cannot set it globally, however I can set it per process (if, for example I start app with systemd).